Scanned Mesh Boolean Doesnt Cut Into Object Correctly
I have a scanned front bumper which comes with problems on its own.
Now i have a modeled mesh over the scanned bumper, and i want to use the bumper to boolean a surface over my mesh, so the mesh will fit nicely over the scanned bumper.
Now when i try to boolean it it cuts the mesh in all ways except for the way it has to.
I have tried adding a solidify modifier on both meshes. I have doubel checked that the normals face outwards. i have made sure the scale and everything is correct and reset, but i still cant get it to work the way it should.
Am i missing something obvious?
File link:
https://we.tl/t-yeACjvUv8c
Had to use wetransfer since the file size was too large for blender-exchange because of the scanned mesh

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Could you explain "i want to use the bumper to boolean a surface over my mesh" ? Under boolean modifier, there are 3 operations : Intersect, Union, Difference. Do you want to "cut" the modeled bumper (in green ?) with the scanned one (in grey ?) ?

No not bumper boolean, i use a mesh of a car bumper, like the front bumper of a car that i have scanned in. The model I am using to cut into my boolean is the mesh of a car bumper
